# How to let application crash in XCode iOS simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I would like to test if my UncaughtExceptionHandler works by throwing exception at some point. However when trying it in Simulator app actually don't crash but instead jump into XCode's breakpoint. How can I disable this and let app just crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your application is installed in the Simulator you can stop it from Xcode, then go to the Home screen and click (tap) on it to launch it directly just like you would on a device.

Alternatively you can go to Debug, Detach in Xcode to detach the debugger while leaving the app running.

Comment: Detatch the debugger is what I was looking for. Thank you.